# WPF grid validation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have editable grid, which binds on Collection of `GridRow` (custom class, described rows for grid).
 `GridRow` has property `Parameter` `(int)`, which should be edited by user.
So simple validation works fine:I can't insert in this field something like "text" or something else.
But I need validation on whole grid. In column `Parameter` on grid can be only one symbol '1', two'2', three '3', two '5'.
So for example if I already insert into grid values '1,2,3' and I try to insert '1', app should show me validation message.
I try to do this with `IDataErrorInfo`, but I can't get in setter whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue with subscribing on 'CellVaildate' event.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you'd be interested in a blog article I have about [validating business rules in MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/validating-business-rules-in-mvvm/)?

It allows you to attach Model validation code from the ViewModel, and should let you accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
public class GridViewModel
{
    // Kept this generic to reduce code here, but it
    // should be a full property with PropertyChange notification
    public ObservableCollection<GridRowModel> GridRows{ get; set; }

    public UsersViewModel()
    {
        GridRows = GetGridRows();

        // Add the validation delegate to the UserModels
        foreach(var row in GridRows)
            user.AddValidationErrorDelegate(ValidateGridRow);
    }

    // User Validation Delegate to verify UserName is unique
    private string ValidateGridRow(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == "Parameter")
        {
            var row = (GridRow)sender;
            var existingCount = GridRows.Count(p => 
                p.Parameter == row.Parameter && p != row);

            switch(row.Parameter)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (existingCount >= 0)
                        return string.Format("{0}s are already taken", row.Parameter);
                case 2: case 5:
                    if (existingCount >= 1)
                        return string.Format("{0}s are already taken", row.Parameter);
                case 3:
                    if (existingCount >= 2)
                        return string.Format("{0}s are already taken", row.Parameter);
             }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```